# ANR Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x50000014 (has extras) } issue

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my Android TV App I am calling Broadcast receiver for every 1 minute doing a small operation and For every 15 minutes calling a request in `onRecieve()` doing response parsing using AsyncTask and loading 30 same images with data at a time, I am not doing much work on UI Thread even though my App is showing "App not responding" issue.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

ANR gets triggered if the broadcast receiver hasn't finished executing in 10 seconds.

Also, you can take a look at **/data/anr/traces.txt** to analyze the function causing this issue. Please refer to the following link to understand the causes of ANR: [Keeping your app responsive](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html).